# stream_context_create returns NULL

Tags: php, apple-push-notifications, filestream, ini

```
<?php var_dump(stream_context_create(array()));?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php
sez Return Values: A stream context resource.
the return value should not be NULL but it is,
there are no functions disable via php

```
<?php  var_dump( ini_get('disabled_functions'));?>
```

returns a blank string

what else could it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do need to specify what KIND of stream you want to establish. You don't walk into a store and say "give me something!", you have to say "give me an apple" or "give me a steak". Passing in a blank array is basically the exact same thing.

Answer (score 1):

this is a bug for typecast, try this:

```
echo var_export(''.stream_context_create());
```

Comment: Heh, this looked so bizarre I thought it couldn't be right, but is!
A little more obvious is to try `(string)stream_context_create()`